# react-virtualized list item does not re-render with changed props until I scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a react-virtualized list (using List component) like this:

```
renderItem = ({ index, key, style }) => {
  const {
    entries,
    projectId,
  } = this.props;
  const entry = entries[index];

  return (
    <div key={key} style={style}>
      <MyItem
        entry={entry}
        entryIndex={index}
        projectId={projectId}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

<List
  rowHeight={75}
  rowRenderer={this.renderItem}
  rowCount={entries.length}
  width={780}
  height={1000}
/>
```

`MyItem` is connected to a redux store and can be interacted with. However it's not reflecting any of the changes on the screen until I scroll the list, as soon as I scroll I see the list item as it should be with the updates since `MyItem's` `render()` is finally called.

How can I get react-virtualized to re-render the list item when a prop changes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you can simply pass the props in question to your list. It would look something like this.

```
<List
  rowHeight={75}
  rowRenderer={this.renderItem}
  rowCount={entries.length}
  width={780}
  height={1000}
  data={entries} // this prop can be called anything
/>
```

Of course the List does not actually have a prop called `data`, but passing your dataset as a prop will tell the List to re-render when the data changes.

Under the hood, List and other components make use of PureComponent, which will trigger re-render any time the props you pass to them change. You can read more on this [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized#pass-thru-props).

NOTE: I have not actually ever done this with the list component, but have made this work with the MultiGrid component. In my use case, I allowed the user to sort the data, and the dataset needed to be passed to the MultiGrid so that it would re-render when the data changed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't find this solution in the document of react-virtualized, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this works !!! .. you just need to pass an additional property which is unique for next time so that List component find the new changes in shallowCompare and get recall the given re-render method.

Comment: data={Math.random()} is generic solution.

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck with the same problem. this solution helped me

Comment: Thanks! In my case I was using the Autosizer component(from the same author of react-virtualized) in conjunction with the List, so I had to also add a props on it related to what I had put in the data property of the List in order to make the re-render work. Since the Autosizer doesn't have a data property, in this example you could do something like <Autosizer key={entries.length}>//List Component...</>